# Kendo Spreadsheet menu: remove merge option

Tags: asp.net-core, kendo-ui, telerik, kendospreadsheet

By default in the Telerik Kendo Menu we have copy, paste, cut and merge. Is there a way to remove the "merge" option?

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var el = $('#mySpreadSheet');
    var spreadsheet = el.getKendoSpreadsheet();
    spreadsheet.cellContextMenu().remove("?merge?"); // ??
```

Answer (score 1):

I post the answer given by telerik team as a ticket:

In order to remove the merge menuitem from the Kendo UI Spreadsheet's contextMenu, utilize the [remove](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/contextmenu/methods/remove?_ga=2.151259577.120359856.1657205230-734630181.1647605657) method with the specific selector:

```
$(function() {
    var spreadsheet = $("#spreadsheet").kendoSpreadsheet().data("kendoSpreadsheet"),
        cellContextMenu = spreadsheet.cellContextMenu();
  
  //use a selector to remove a particular item
  cellContextMenu.remove($("ul.k-spreadsheet-cell-context-menu li[data-action='merge']"));
  
  //removes the unneeded separator
  cellContextMenu.remove($("ul.k-spreadsheet-cell-context-menu li.k-menu-separator"));
});
```

Please take a look at the [following Progress Kendo UI Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/@PMcDonou/OjatuPAX?_ga=2.138428851.120359856.1657205230-734630181.1647605657) which demonstrates the above and let me know if you have any questions.